# Calculating a variable in R using a look-up table with booleans

Tags: r

I have two datasets: one dataset that has dichotomous variables with product ingredients (`m`) and a look-up table that maps ingredients to product labels using boolean terms (e.g. whether the ingredient is `TRUE` or `FALSE` after coalescing across several variables).

For example, `m` might look like:

```
id    milk  cheese eggs
001   TRUE  TRUE   FALSE
002   FALSE FALSE  TRUE
003   FALSE FALSE  FALSE
```

And then the look-up table `ingred` might look like:

```
label            boolean  ingredients
vegan            FALSE    milk, cheese, eggs
gluten_free      FALSE    wheat, rye, barley
```

The desired output is that `m` will contain a new field that coalesces `TRUE/FALSE` after matching the boolean values for ingredients (represented by column names) to the comma-separated values in the lookup table.

```
id    milk  cheese eggs   wheat   barely  rye    vegan   gluten_free
001   TRUE  TRUE   FALSE  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
002   FALSE FALSE  TRUE   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE  FALSE   FALSE
003   FALSE FALSE  FALSE  TRUE    FALSE   FALSE  TRUE    FALSE
```

I have a general idea to that the comma-separated values in `ingred` need to be transposed into a matrix, but I'm unsure how to combine `m` and `ingred` to get the desired output. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have more rows in `ingred` and if so, would there be other combination values

Comment: @akrun Yes - I will modify my example. Because the datasets I am working with are proprietary and very complex, I simplified the example but will add more texture to improve the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to split the 'ingredients' column of second dataset by the delimiter (`", "`) into a `list` of vectors, use `Map` to loop over the `list` along with the corresponding elements of 'boolean' column,  subset the columns of the first dataset based on the splitted names, check whether it is not equal to 'boolean' value, do a row wise `sum` and negate (`!`)

```
df1[df2$label] <- Map(function(x, y) !rowSums(df1[x] != y), 
               strsplit(df2$ingredients, ", "), df2$boolean)

df1
#  id  milk cheese  eggs wheat barley   rye vegan gluten_free
#1  1  TRUE   TRUE FALSE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE        TRUE
#2  2 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE FALSE   TRUE FALSE FALSE       FALSE
#3  3 FALSE  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE  TRUE       FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, milk = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), cheese = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE), eggs = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), wheat = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE), barley = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), rye = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(label = c("vegan", "gluten_free"), boolean = c(FALSE, 
FALSE), ingredients = c("milk, cheese, eggs", "wheat, rye, barley"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```